# Unable to connect to the configuration database in SP2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am using SP 2010.

1. I created a new site collection from central admin.
2. and it gave me "site created successfully"
3. when I visit the new site collection, I get below error:

> Cannot connect to the configuration database

What are my options?

Comment: belongs on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: Check most of the causes for this issue at [Can not connect to the configuration database](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/22/cannot-connect-to-the-configuration-database/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably the app pool you are running your site collection under, have you got any other site collections in the same web application?

If not take a look at the permissions on the app pool for that web app

Comment: Thanks Luke. That did the trick. I had changed some of the app pool account last night so I changed it back to what it was. Now it's all fine. Thanks again for being prompt and helpful.

Comment: no problems, ive spent many hours banging my head against a wall with SP as well ;)

Comment: @LukeMcGregor: I'm facing the issue as mentioned in question but please explain me what exactly is meant in the answer by you? Please guide me!

Answer (score 5):

Go to services (Start --> Run --> Type services.msc) and start the service **SQL Server(SHAREPOINT)**

Comment: This happened to me after I added my server to a domain. I had to change the service account that was executing the service to a domain account and change its permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This problem came to me after a password expired in the AD and had to be updated. 
When i changed the password i had to sync in to the ad and used this site: http://info.izzy.org/Blog/archive/2010/08/04/how-to-fix-an-out-of-sync-password-issue-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Then i found out that the problem was that SharePoint Timer Service wasnt running och the Front end server. So I had to do an iisreset on the front end server to get the Service to start, since the account using the service was the account with a new password. And then everything was back on track again!

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was secondary replica of  Always on Was Empty and does not have Config database

i have configured an always Solution and at start i connect sharepoint to alias via cliconfig.exe and alias was connecting to AG listener
fail over back to instance where Config db exists solved my problem